# Reading file line by line and tokenizing lines

Tags: c++, tokenize

I have a file with multiple lines.
lines contain integers separated by commas

In the following code it only parses the first line, but not the renaming lines. Any insight about I am doing wrong ?

```
void parseLines(std::ifstream &myfile){
  std::string line, token;
  std::stringstream ss; 
  int i;
  vector<int> r;
  while(myfile) {
    getline(myfile, line);
    ss.str("");
    ss.str(line);
    if(myfile){
      cout << "SS" << ss.str() << endl;
      while (std::getline(ss, token, ',')){
        std::cout << token << std::endl;  
      }   
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: You want while`(getline(myfile, line))`.  Also, create the stringstream inside the loop.

Comment: If this is on Windows, is the file formatted with the correct CRLF line endings?

Comment: Search the internet for "stackoverflow c++ read file CSV".

Answer (score 2):

> Any insight about I am doing wrong?

The state of `ss` needs to be reset before data from the second line can be read.

Better yet, move the construction of `ss` inside the loop.

While at it,

1. replace `while(myfile)` by `while(getline(myfile, line))`.
2. Move the declaration of `token` inside the loop.

---

```
void parseLines(std::ifstream &myfile){
   std::string line;
   int i;
   vector<int> r;
   while( getline(myfile, line) )
   {
      std::stringstream ss(line); 
      std::string token;
      while (std::getline(ss, token, ',')){
         std::cout << token << std::endl;  
      }   
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is the `stringstream` is not local to the while loop.  When you read from the `stringstream` the first time you exhaust the stream which causes the EOF flag to be set.  If you do not clear that then you will never read any more information from it even if you load more.  The simplest way to get around this is to make the `stringstream` local to the loop body so you start off with a fresh one on each iteration and you do no have to worry about cleaning up the flags.  That would make your code look like

```
while(getline(myfile, line)) // also moved the line reading here to control when to stop the loop
{
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    while (std::getline(ss, token, ',')){
        std::cout << token << std::endl;  
    }
}
```